# Kivy - setting the background color of a button.

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to set the background color of a button to blue using Kivy. I went to an RGB generation website and copied the values from there for the color I wanted however it doesn't seem to be working. My Kivy code for the button is here:

```
Button:
        text: 'Calories'
        font_size: 30
        on_release: app.root.current = 'calories'
        background_normal: ' '
        background_color: (51, 23, 186.0, 1)
```

When I run this the button goes pure white. I am also curious as to how I would get the text to change color.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the examples at [github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=background_color) it seems the values aren't 0-255 RGB like you might expect but are 0.0-1.1

```
bubble.background_color = (1, 0, 0, .5) #50% translucent red
background_color: .8, .8, 0, 1
```

etc.

You'll probably need something like

```
background_color: .2, .1, .73, 1
```

Comment: Ah yeah that worked, do you know how I would navigate through little and darker shades of blue though?

Comment: The values are just scaled so take your desired RGB values (e.g. 51, 23, 186 from your original example) and divide each by 255.  Blue is the third value so make the .73 a larger value and you'll get darker blue.

Answer (score -1):

delete background_normal: ' ', just use background_color: (R, G, B, A) pick a color in this [tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Herramienta_para_seleccionar_color) and divide R, G and B by 100 A=always 1 (transparency), for example if you choose (255, 79, 25, 1) write instead (2.55, 0.79, 0.25, 1).

Comment: dude what the hell, why is it divided by 100??? And it works!!